# Symfony2 - CalendarBundle - How to fetch user informations from database to render on calendar

Tags: php, sql, symfony, calendar

So, i am new to Symfony and i'm trying to create a functional calendar based application with events rendered from the database using [calendar-bundle](https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle).

Passing with the documentation i was able to make a relationship between users and events rendered on the calendar but i'm stuck passing particular data, more exactly the user name.

Below is it shown the EventEntity which is responsible for calendar event's details.

```
<?php
namespace ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Entity;

/**
* Class for holding a calendar event's details.
*
* @author Mike Yudin <mikeyudin@gmail.com>
*/

class EventEntity
{
/**
 * @var mixed Unique identifier of this event (optional).
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string Title/label of the calendar event.
 */
protected $title;

/**
 * @var string URL Relative to current path.
 */
protected $url;

/**
 * @var string HTML color code for the bg color of the event label.
 */
protected $bgColor;

/**
 * @var string HTML color code for the foregorund color of the event label.
 */
protected $fgColor;

/**
 * @var string css class for the event label
 */
protected $cssClass;

/**
 * @var \DateTime DateTime object of the event start date/time.
 */
protected $startDatetime;

/**
 * @var \DateTime DateTime object of the event end date/time.
 */
protected $endDatetime;

/**
 * @var boolean Is this an all day event?
 */
protected $allDay = false;

/**
 * @var array Non-standard fields
 */
protected $otherFields = array();

public function __construct($title, \DateTime $startDatetime, \DateTime $endDatetime = null, $allDay = false)
{
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->startDatetime = $startDatetime;
    $this->setAllDay($allDay);

    if ($endDatetime === null && $this->allDay === false) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Must specify an event End DateTime if not an all day event.");
    }

    $this->endDatetime = $endDatetime;
}

/**
 * Convert calendar event details to an array
 *
 * @return array $event
 */
public function toArray()
{
    $event = array();

    if ($this->id !== null) {
        $event['id'] = $this->id;
    }

    $event['title'] = $this->title;
    $event['start'] = $this->startDatetime->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP");

    if ($this->url !== null) {
        $event['url'] = $this->url;
    }

    if ($this->bgColor !== null) {
        $event['backgroundColor'] = $this->bgColor;
        $event['borderColor'] = $this->bgColor;
    }

    if ($this->fgColor !== null) {
        $event['textColor'] = $this->fgColor;
    }

    if ($this->cssClass !== null) {
        $event['className'] = $this->cssClass;
    }

    if ($this->endDatetime !== null) {
        $event['end'] = $this->endDatetime->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP");
    }

    $event['allDay'] = $this->allDay;

    foreach ($this->otherFields as $field => $value) {
        $event[$field] = $value;
    }

    return $event;
}

public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;
}

public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

public function setUrl($url)
{
    $this->url = $url;
}

public function getUrl()
{
    return $this->url;
}

public function setBgColor($color)
{
    $this->bgColor = $color;
}

public function getBgColor()
{
    return $this->bgColor;
}

public function setFgColor($color)
{
    $this->fgColor = $color;
}

public function getFgColor()
{
    return $this->fgColor;
}

public function setCssClass($class)
{
    $this->cssClass = $class;
}

public function getCssClass()
{
    return $this->cssClass;
}

public function setStartDatetime(\DateTime $start)
{
    $this->startDatetime = $start;
}

public function getStartDatetime()
{
    return $this->startDatetime;
}

public function setEndDatetime(\DateTime $end)
{
    $this->endDatetime = $end;
}

public function getEndDatetime()
{
    return $this->endDatetime;
}

public function setAllDay($allDay = false)
{
    $this->allDay = (boolean) $allDay;
}

public function getAllDay()
{
    return $this->allDay;
}

/**
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $value
 */
public function addField($name, $value)
{
    $this->otherFields[$name] = $value;
}

/**
 * @param string $name
 */
public function removeField($name)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($name, $this->otherFields)) {
        return;
    }

    unset($this->otherFields[$name]);
}
}
```

Besides this i have the CalendarEventListener.php which is responsible for data sent to render on the calendar:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Event\CalendarEvent;
use ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Entity\EventEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CalendarEventListener
{
private $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

public function loadEvents(CalendarEvent $calendarEvent)
{
    $startDate = $calendarEvent->getStartEventDate();
    $endDate = $calendarEvent->getEndEventDate();

    // The original request so you can get filters from the calendar
    // Use the filter in your query for example

    $request = $calendarEvent->getRequest();
    $filter = $request->get('filter');


    // load events using your custom logic here,
    // for instance, retrieving events from a repository

    $companyEvents = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:companyEvents')
                      ->createQueryBuilder('companyEvents')
                      ->where('companyEvents.startEventDate BETWEEN :startEventDate and :endEventDate')
                      ->setParameter('startEventDate', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                      ->setParameter('endEventDate', $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                      ->getQuery()->getResult();

    // $companyEvents and $companyEvent in this example
    // represent entities from your database, NOT instances of EventEntity
    // within this bundle.
    //
    // Create EventEntity instances and populate it's properties with data
    // from your own entities/database values.

    foreach($companyEvents as $companyEvent) {


            $eventEntity = new EventEntity($companyEvent->getEventName(),
                                                                    //   
                                                                         $companyEvent->getStartEventDate(),
                                                                         $companyEvent->getEndEventDate()
                                                                         ,null, true);
        //optional calendar event settings
        $eventEntity->setAllDay(true); // default is false, set to true if this is an all day event
        $eventEntity->setBgColor('#3366ff'); //set the background color of the event's label
        $eventEntity->setFgColor('#FFFFFF'); //set the foreground color of the event's label
        $eventEntity->setUrl('http://www.google.com'); // url to send user to when event label is clicked
        $eventEntity->setCssClass('my-custom-class'); // a custom class you may want to apply to event labels

        //finally, add the event to the CalendarEvent for displaying on the calendar
        $calendarEvent->addEvent($eventEntity);

    }
}
}
```

And the companyEvents entity for structuring events:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="companyEvents")
*/
class companyEvents
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
* events are created by users
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="events")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="event_name")
 */
private $eventName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="event_date", type="datetime")
 */
private $eventDate;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="startEventDate", type="datetime")
 */
 private $startEventDate;

 /**
  * @ORM\Column(name="endEventDate", type="datetime")
  */
  private $endEventDate;

/**
 * Set eventName
 *
 * @param string $eventName
 *
 * @return companyEvents
 */
public function setEventName($eventName)
{
    $this->eventName = $eventName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get eventName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEventName()
{
    return $this->eventName;
}

/**
 * Set eventDate
 *
 * @param string $eventDate
 *
 * @return CompanyEvents
 */
public function setEventDate($eventDate)
{
    $this->eventDate = $eventDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get eventDate
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEventDate()
{
    return $this->eventDate;
}

/**
* Set start event date
* @param string $startEventDate
*
* @return companyEvents
*/
public function setStartEventDate($startEventDate)
{
    $this->startEventDate = $startEventDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
*Get start event date
* @return string
*/
public function getStartEventDate()
{
    return $this->startEventDate;
}

/**
* Set start event date
* @param string $endEventDate
*
* @return companyEvents
*/
public function setEndEventDate($endEventDate)
{
    $this->endEventDate = $endEventDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
*Get start event date
* @return string
*/
public function getEndEventDate()
{
    return $this->endEventDate;
}

/**
* set user relationship
* @param string $user_id
*
* @return companyEvents
*/
public function setUser($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    return $this;
}
/**
* @return string
*/
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

}

So, my problem is that instead of getEventName passed here:

```
$eventEntity = new EventEntity($companyEvent->getEventName(),
                              $companyEvent->getStartEventDate(),
                              $companyEvent->getEndEventDate()
                              ,null, true);
```

i want to pass the particular user name which belongs to the specific event but when i change the getEventName() (WHICH RENDERS THE TITLE OF THE EVENT) with any other function (i have tried to even pass just the user_id from the entity), nothing else is shown in the calendar without dumping any error.

Any hints on resolving this problem will be hardly appreciated :) !

Comment: What do you want to achieve by passing the user name to the EventEntity?

Comment: I want to render the user name of the person who created the event instead of event's title. I've created the getUser() function to pass the user_id and replaced the getEventName() with it, but nothing happens and the events doesen't render anymore.

Comment: Do you have a relationship between companyEvents and User, right? So you can change the getEventName() to return the user name like this

public function getEventName()
{
    return $this->user->getName();
}

Comment: I've added an answer with more details on what you could do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render the username in the event's title you can change the `getEventName` method to return the user name:

```
public function getEventName()
{
    return $this->user->getUsername();
}
```

This way you won't have to change the `CalendarEventListener` code.

Remember to remove the `eventName` property and it's setter method from the `companyEvents`entity. You should also name the entity CamelCased and in the singular, like this `CompanyEvent`.

Comment: Works like charm ! Didn't know alot about these functions. Thank you very much for support :)

Comment: EDIT: I've tried to use getName() instead of getUsername(); to get the whole name of the user and works brilliant. Again many thanks !